# Symfony 4 : Unsezialise() , ["allowed_classes" => false] error

Tags: php, symfony, web, serialization, symfony4

I'm developing a website with Synfony 4 and created an admin login. I used serialize and unserialize.

```
  /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        // TODO: Implement serialize() method.
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        // TODO: Implement unserialize() method.
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
            ) = $this->unserialize($serialized, ["allowed_classes" => false]);
    }
```

At the end `$this->unserialize($serialized, ["allowed_classes" => false]);` doesn't work and shows *"Method call is provided 2 parameters, but the method signature uses 1 parameters"* as error in Intellij IDEA.
I don't understand what this means and cannot find anything about it.

I think that the basics methods just want `unserialize($serialized)` or something like that but when I fill the form and send it nothing happens.

Comment: `$this->unserialize()` is not the same as PHP's internal `unserialize()` - you want the second

Comment: `$this->unserialize` ?? Thats calling the method you are already in. 1) Bit circular 2) `$this->unserialize()` only has one parameter and you are passing 2 parameters. Loose the `$this` so you are calling just `unserialize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know the context of these methods but using `$this->unserialize(...)`, you are calling the current function (`public function unserialize($serialized){...}`)

You probably want to use the default PHP serializer. So you problably should do the following :

```
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ["allowed_classes" => false]);
}
```

If "nothing happens", without any more information about that problem, we won't be able to help you !
Did you try to add any dump to check what's happening ?